# splitting url and getting values from that URl in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi say I have a column in data frame 
name submission contains - mhttps://ckd.pdc.com/pdc/73ba5189-94fd-44aa-88d3-6b36aaa69b02/DDA1610095.zip

I want to one column say Zest and I want the value DDA1610095 in that column.

and a new column say type and want .zip in that column how to do that using pandas.

Comment: please add an example from your data and your expected output

Comment: example url - https://ckd.pdc.com/pdc/73ba5189-94fd-44aa-88d3-6b36aaa69b02/DDA1610095.zip ,   expected - .zip in separate column and 'DDA1610095 in a separate column

Comment: You should try to ask a question in a better and more formatted manner check the rules for posting questions as others don't know your problem so being clear and explicit is important. I've tried to answer your question. don't be discouraged!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a `str.split` and add another `str` so you can index each row.

```
data = [{'ID' : '1',
    'URL':  'https://ckd.pdc.com/pdc/73ba5189-94fd-44aa-88d3-6b36aaa69b02/DDA1610095.zip'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)



     print(df)
            ID  URL
    0   1   https://ckd.pdc.com/pdc/73ba5189-94fd-44aa-88d...

    #Get the file name and replace zip (probably a more elegant way to do this) 
    df['Zest'] = df.URL.str.split('/').str[-1].str.replace('.zip','')
    #assign the type into the next column. 
    df['Type'] = df.URL.str.split('.').str[-1]
    print(df)

    ID  URL                                                 Zest       Type
0   1   https://ckd.pdc.com/pdc/73ba5189-94fd-44aa-88d...   DDA1610095 zip
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `str.split` to extract the zip from the url

```
df 
                                                                           url
0  mhttps://ckd.pdc.com/pdc/73ba5189-94fd-44aa-88d3-6b36aaa69b02/DDA1610095.zip
```

---

```
df['zip'] = df.url.str.split('/',expand=True).T[0] \
        [df.url.str.split('/',expand=True).T.shape[0]-1]

df.T
Out[46]: 
                                                                                0
url  mhttps://ckd.pdc.com/pdc/73ba5189-94fd-44aa-88d3-6b36aaa69b02/DDA1610095.zip
zip                                                                DDA1610095.zip
```